# React Native Custom UI Native Module

Tags: javascript, react-native

i was searching at google, but only find some tutorials on do basic UI Module, i want to archive this

```
<MyCustomView>
   <View>...</View>
</MyCustomView>
```

is there any way to create a UI Module for Android doing this?

after trying with the tutorials that i found, android gives me and error that says `... can not be cast to ViewGroup`

Comment: Not quite clear what you trying to do.

Comment: im trying to create a native UI module, that allows me to put more views as a children of it

Comment: What is custom view? Native code? React Native Component?